# Always prompted to allow windows installer to run when clicking shortcut on start menu

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, windows-installer

I have an application installed, and when I click on the shortcut to it from the start menu I am first prompted by the MSI installer and a UAC prompt.  If the I allow the specified `.msi` file (`C:\Windows\Installer\something.msi`) to run, then the standard Windows installer window for the application shows up briefly with a progress bar and then my application runs.  This happens every time.

If I just double-click the `.exe` that the shortcut points to in `Program Files`, then I don't see this.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times.  I have a feeling there is something broken in the windows installer database (if such a thing exists).  Is there a tool or something that could help diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: While OG Chuck Low's answer is correct, the cleanup utility has been [superseded](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/does-windows-installer-cleanup-utility-work-in/164444db-1254-4181-b585-389918e7a286) by Windows 7's [Install and Uninstall Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) utility. The tool can be run directly from the linked page. I hope that helps!

Comment: Nice call.  I knew they had a "Fix It" utility but I was too lazy to look.  I vote for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks but this isn't resolving the issue.  I can install and uninstall the app with no problems, it it just that the shortcut seems to want windows installer involved for some reason.

Comment: Just to make sure I get ya... you are saying you tried it and it didn't resolve your issue?  Or you look and think "That won't work" so did not try it?  If you tried it and it it's not working then I might suggest, since you noted double clicking the .EXE in the program directory didn't manifest the issue, just replace the target in your shortcut icon to the .EXE file.

Comment: And if that don't work, just delete the desktop icon and then in the directory, make a shortcut off the .EXE file and then drop that on your desktop and see if that works properly.

Comment: I tried the tool and it didn't fix it.  I can create a separate shortcut and that works fine also.  However, whenever I update the software (which is about once a week) I might have to deal with the weird shortcut issue again.  This isn't a huge deal but I'm concerned that something is broken in Windows Installer that is causing this and might lead to bigger issues down the road.  Also, the shortcut seems to be a special one because when I right-click it and go to properties, the target field is disabled.

Comment: That does suck a little :(  I don't really have any other ideas though... can you try installing the application on another computer and seeing if it still has the same issue there as well?  Also... I think there is a way to sort of... "reset"? the Windows Installer but I can't promise nuthin' lol... I am REACHING here lol.

Comment: Even if you can't change that target field... can you see if there are any odd switches and stuff in the target line?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the application works fine on other machines (same version of Windows too).  The target field doesn't contain a full path like a normal shortcut does.  This seems to be some type of special windows installer shortcut that is somehow hooking into the launch process for some reason.